# DrawableWrapperLollipop.setTintList() throws NullPointerException in preview window and in unit tests with Robolectric

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-support-library, android-drawable

`DrawableWrapperLollipop.setTintList(DrawableWrapperLollipop.java:67)` throws `NullPointerException` when calling `mDrawable.setTintList(tint)`, i.e. `mDrawable` is `null`.

Code used to reproduce:

```java
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
ColorStateList colorStateList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(), R.color.icon_state_tint_selector);

Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(button.getDrawable());
DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable, colorStateList);
button.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

This code is inside custom view constructor.

Running on the device works fine - no exception, tinting works.

But while instantiating the custom view in unit tests with Robolectric or opening preview window of layout that uses this custom view, the following exception is thrown:

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperLollipop.setTintList(DrawableWrapperLollipop.java:67)
    at android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompatLollipop.setTintList(DrawableCompatLollipop.java:49)
    at android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat$LollipopDrawableImpl.setTintList(DrawableCompat.java:228)
    at android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.java:390)
    at com.example.MyCustomView.<init>(MyCustomView.java:101)
    ...
```

Support library version: 23.2.1 
Android Studio version: 2.0 beta 7 
Robolectric version: 3.0

This is the drawable:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#8A000000"
        android:pathData="M19,13H5V11H19V13Z" />

</vector>
```

And this is the `icon_state_tint_selector`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/icon_state_tint_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/icon_state_tint_activated" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/icon_state_tint_normal" />

</selector>
```

The `@color/icon_state_tint_*` are just plain hex values.